# UIScrollView does not rotate to landscape

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, autorotate

This is most def something very simple, but it is driving me crazy, cant figure it out.

**It was very simple, see solution below**

My app does not auto rotate. It is just stuck in portrait.

My AppDelegate creates a viewController witch has shouldAutorotate uncommented an simply returns yes.

My viewController sets up a scrollview(x) as it's view and adds a subclassed custom scrollview(y) as its subview.

Than scrollview(y) adds UIView as it's subview. This UIView acts as a content view and has 1 or multiple other UIViews as subview.

So: AppDelegate -> scrollView(x) -> scrollView(y) -> UIView -> 1 or more UIView's

I have a line displayed when shouldAutorotate is called. This happens 2x when the application has finished loading. When I rotate the simulator, nothing happens, shouldAutorotate is not called apparently because I don't see a line displayed in my log.

Is there a property on the UIScrollview which prevents it from rotating?

**Update**: I've just changed my plist.info to start the app in landscape. Now the app is stuck in landscape and does not rotate to portrait.

**FYI**: I'm not using interface builder, all done in code.

Comment: Scrollviews can rotate normally. I've just created a simple view based app and added a scrollview to the xib's view. Just added shouldAutoRotate... to the viewController.

Comment: Thanks Nick, i've tested that as well. Basically my app follows the PhotoScroller example of apple. This example also rotates, once you add the shouldAutorotate method.

Comment: But your app doesn't right? Are you using a some versioning software like git? Going back some steps when the app was very simple could help and see if the rotation did work.

Comment: Correct, my app does not rotate. No, i'm not using git, just plain standard stuff supplied with xcode. I'll try to go back to basics tomorrow, it's getting late (2200 CET), thanks for the tip Nick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**: Turns out I was a bit to memory conservative. In my app delegate I would create an instance of a viewController, add it to the window, and than called release on it, figuring it was added to the window so I wouldn't need it anymore. Bad idea. 
The shouldAutorotate messages is therefore sent to an object that does not exist anymore. I did get a message in my console about a message being sent to a released object, but only multiple seconds (20 or so) after I rotated the simulator.

I've learned that you should always keep a reference to your "main/root viewController" as an instance variable in appDelegate

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution, you can eve accept it for yourself.